# How efficient in terms of speed is a Filterable custom ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, performance, android-arrayadapter, text-search, android-filterable

I need to search a **varchar** column of **SQLite** database for a word from my app and show the results in a listview. Currently I'm using **Mensa library** [Mensa Github Link](https://github.com/dell-oss/Mensa) because of the speed it offers for even very very long texts. In another project I've also used **Filterable** alongwith a custom **ArrayAdapter** which filters listitems based on text matching. I was wondering whether i could replace Mensa usage with the **Filterable** approach without compromising on the search efficiency because **Mensa library increases the APK size by 3.37 MB**

Comment: Why don't you just try it and compare?

Answer (score 1):

I've checked the jar file of the Mensa library, and it is that big because they include their `animal.keywords` testing database inside the jar.

Rename the mensa-1.0.1.jar to `mensa-1.0.1.zip`, and open it with your archive manager. Navigate to `com/dell/mensa/testutils/` and delete the `animals.keywords` file. Now rename it back to `mensa-1.0.1.jar`, and continue using it. The file should be **104.5 kB** now.

Comment: Wow , keen observer i must say. I never looked into the jar file.!!  But I'd still like to compare the difference in efficiency between Filterable and Mensa, though I like Mensa a lot. Thanks for the quick answer. I've implemented and tested the app again, it works !

Comment: As Mike M. said, you should just test it yourself :) This is quite a specific use-case, chances are you are the first one doing it.